# Почему я получаю от своего сервера объект ответа, а не сам ответ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

У меня есть два `.js` файла.

Первый отправляет запрос(использую node-fetch):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(e => { console.log(e); });
```

Второй - сервер, получающий запрос:

```
const http = require('http');
let server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text\plain"});
    if(request.method == "GET") {
        response.end("received GET request.");
    }
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running on port 8000");
```

Когда я запускаю первый скрипт, я получаю такой ответ:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
     status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }
```

При этом, когда я обращаюсь к серверу при помощи curl(пишу в cmd `curl 127.0.0.1:8000`), я получаю тот ответ, который нужен мне:

```
received GET request.
```

Так вот, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы при отправке запроса с первого скрипта на мой сервер(второй скрипт), я получал строку `received GET request.`, а не объект ответа?

Скажу сразу, что в back-end`e я не очень разбираюсь, поэтому, может быть, код для сервера работает не так, как я ожидаю.

Comment: После первого then() выполнения `fetch` он должен вернуть переведённый ответ в определённом виде, таком как blob, text, json (в зависимости от того что возвращаете). Поэтому напишите так: .fetch(...).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Документацию](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#plain-text-or-html) пробовали читать?

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```